# How can I detect specific element is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please follow these two steps:

- focus on the `input` by clicking in it
- and now click on the `button`

```js
$("input").on({
    focusout: function() {
     this.value += "one|";
    }
});

$("button").on("click", function(){
  $old_val = $("input").val();
  $("input").val($old_val+"two|");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<button>Add "two"</button>
```

The result will be: `one|two|`! Well I don't want this. I want to disable `focusout` when I click on the button. How can I do that?

Expected result after following those two steps should be `two|`.

Comment: focusout occurs before the button click, so you can't "disable focusout when you click the button" as it's already fired.

Comment: @freedomn-m Can't I set a `if` condition in the `focusout` to check next event and if next event is clicking on the button then returns false ?

Comment: Can you detail your use-case requirement?  What are you trying to acheive (beyond the "I want it to be "two|" - why should it be this?)   This looks like an XY Problem: where you're trying to solve X by doing Y and so want to know how to Y - if we know what X is, we can help

Comment: eg why does focusout add "one|"?  What is that meant to achieve?

Comment: @freedomn-m I'm trying to make a autocomplete box exactly like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8fNU.png). In the image I provided, if you focusout of the input, it makes a `jav` tag for you. And if you click on `java` tag, it will create just `java` tag for you, not both `jav` and `java` tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to prevent the button from calling the default `mousedown` event which is where browsers change the focus. Using `e.preventDefault()` will stop this from happening if you assign it to the `mousedown` event on the button.

```js
$("input").on({
    focusout: function() {
     this.value += "one|";
    }
});
$("button").on("mousedown", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); 
});
$("button").on("click", function(){
  $old_val = $("input").val();
  $("input").val($old_val+"two|");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<button>Add "two"</button>
```

Comment: I guess you deleted the comment, but it doesn't disable focusout... run the snippet and click the input and then click anywhere besides the button

Comment: What this does is effectively change the order of the events by firing the click before the focusout, thus allowing OP to add code to remove the focusout... or something :)

Comment: @freedomn-m Yeah .. Great idea it is, isn't it ? `;-)`